# why are there jagged shapes when I bridge edges of two things?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I was connecting one cylindrical shape to another, (I was modeling a leg and connecting the foot to the leg )they had slightly different amount of vertices. When I connected them using bridge edge loops, it had these triangles as faces where the gap was between the two cylindrical shapes. I wanted the transition from one shape to another to be smooth, but I got these jagged triangles to fit the gap.

Comment: That's _because_ the number of vertices is slightly different. If you're modelling by hand, especially for deformation, you have to think ahead as much as you can, anticipating that  the number of vertices will have to be matched. It's not as hard as it seems to begin with, there are patterns which come up again and again.

Comment: You can try selecting the newly created faces and hit Alt + J to convert Tris to Quads. Sometimes it will at least get rid of a few.